# Place to put answers to questions not yet asked?

Tags: discussion

I just had a question typed up ready to submit and just before I submitted it I figured out the answer and solved my own problem.  I searched for the issue here before starting to put the question together and didn't find anything that addressed my issue exactly.  There are lots of posts about popups and selenium but none of them address how to access an AngularJS modal popup that goes full screen, is dynamically built and has no id tags.

My question, is there a place to put general tips or do you have to wait until someone asks the question?

Comment: this question should probably have been asked on Meta

Comment: I have voted to move this to meta.

Answer (score 1):

You can ask it and then answer it yourself.  You won't be awarded reputation, but you will make someone's life easier when they go looking for an answer.

Comment: `You won't be awarded reputation` You still get reputation if people find the post helpful and upvote it (question or answer, or both). You simply don't get any reputation from accepting your post (the +15 for the answer marked as accepted, and +2 for the asker who marks answer as accepted)

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant (no reputation for accepting your own answer).  Sorry I wasn't more specific.

Comment: I fear the down vote like it were the grim reaper

Comment: When I did this I only got downvotes on the question like people are pissed, and no comments as to why. They do seem to like the answer though.